# I'm trying to view four windows in Gee; everything is perfect, but my ui.Map.Linker doesn't work

Tags: google-earth-engine, geemap

```
// set image
var image = ee.Image("LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81260452014268LGN00");


// function to create map 1
function createMap1() {
  var map = new ui.Map();
  map.addLayer(image.select(['B6','B5','B8']), {}, 'image');
  var water = image.expression('(b(7)-b(4))/(b(7)+b(4)) > -0.05');
  map.addLayer(water.mask(water), {palette:['3182bd']}, 'water');
  map.add(ui.Label('Screen 1', {position:'bottom-center'}));
  return map;
}

// function to create map 2
function createMap2() {
  var map = new ui.Map();
  map.addLayer(image.select(['B6','B5','B8']), {}, 'image');
  var water = image.expression('(b(7)-b(4))/(b(7)+b(4)) > -0.05');
  map.addLayer(water.mask(water), {palette:['f442f1']}, 'water');
  map.add(ui.Label('Screen 2', {position:'bottom-center'}));
  return map;
}

// function to create map 3
function createMap3() {
  var map = new ui.Map();
  map.addLayer(image.select(['B6','B5','B8']), {}, 'image');
  var water = image.expression('(b(7)-b(4))/(b(7)+b(4)) > -0.05');
  map.addLayer(water.mask(water), {palette:['fc071b']}, 'water');
  map.add(ui.Label('Screen 3', {position:'bottom-center'}));
  return map;
}
function createMap4() {
  var map = new ui.Map();
  map.addLayer(image.select(['B6','B5','B8']), {}, 'image');
  var water = image.expression('(b(7)-b(4))/(b(7)+b(4)) > -0.05');
  map.addLayer(water.mask(water), {palette:['fc071b']}, 'water');
  map.add(ui.Label('Screen 3', {position:'bottom-center'}));
  return map;
}
var linker= ui.Map.Linker([createMap1(), createMap2(), createMap3(), createMap4()]);

print(linker)
var mapgrid = ui.Panel([

ui.Panel([createMap1(), createMap2()],null,{stretch: 'both'}),
ui.Panel([createMap3(), createMap4()],null,{stretch: 'both'}),
],
ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal'), {stretch: 'both'});




var title = ui.Label('xyz', {
  stretch: 'horizontal',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: '24px'
});

// Add the maps and title to the ui.root.

ui.root.widgets().reset([title, mapgrid,]);
ui.root.setLayout(ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('vertical'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map you're creating in the first call to `createMap1()` in the `ui.Map.Linker` call is not the same map that you're displaying, because you're calling `createMap1()` a second time in the `ui.Panel` line.

Put the 4 maps into variables and use the variables instead of calling the 4 functions twice.